# Problems with the BoxCollider2D and Pivot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I make a 2D game in Unity. I have a player with BoxCollider2D and Objects with BoxCollider2D and the player can't go through these Objects like it should but when the player walks from down to the top (topdown PixelRPG) Than he got blocked very early. I will try to show it in the pictures. I tried to change the size of the colliders the layers and more but can't find a solution. [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yUQk.png)[Collision2DChest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEKXK.png)
[Collision2DNPC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2ZHt.png)
[Collision2DWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5qg6.png)

[NoProblem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs0VN.png)

[NoProblemswithObjects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGlaC.png)

[ProblemAgainfromdowntoTop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmqRX.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, it looks like you simply need to resize your BoxCollider2D to fit the player.

[image: Ways to change BoxCollider2D size]

You can either use the **Edit Collider** button, and in the Unity viewport you can click and drag to change the size of the collider, or change the **Size** value in the inspector. Since your collider seems to be too large vertically, change the **Y** value to be smaller.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried and didn't change anything :/

Comment: Do you have any other colliders on your player? Maybe you have colliders on your environment?

Comment: Yes I have a boxcollider on my chest or the npc but I also edit them so it should be no problem. I will upload more pictures in the question.

Comment: Why is the sprite box of the player so large?

Comment: Cause the player is animated and the sprites used vor the animation need different space of pixels. I tried to make the spriteboxes smaller through custom outline in the spriteeditor for every Sprite used for the animation, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: So the sprite box didn't get smaller.. and is still that big

Comment: If the location of the player changes in the animation, the collider **won't move with it.** This means that your animation should always stay in one place, otherwise the collider won't work. I think this may be the problem.

Comment: I know found out it is all about the pivot. But now I got the problem I can't find the right spot for the pivot. Cause when I put the pivot at the bottom I got the same Problem when I want to walk above something. Its all about the pivot.